# How is a user's primary blog determined?

Tags: multisite, user-meta

The `wp_usermeta` database table has a `primary_blog` meta field for each user. Where is the value for that field set in the Admin Panel, and how can I override  the default value?

Answer (score 2):

Every user can set this value on the My Sites admin screen. It defaults to the first blog a user created in the MultiSite instance, if it's unset and the user creates a new blog, that blog becomes his primary blog.